# Cannot login to Nexus 3 docker registry

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, nexus, docker-registry, nexus3

I have set up an AWS EC2 instance with Docker, Nexus3 and a Docker repository in Nexus with HTTP port 8123 and all the necessary settings so that I can see it from Docker. I have added after a lengthy research the right options in my docker config file so that when I run `docker info` I can see my insecure registry set to the right IP address. I can access the url of the Nexus manager from my machine without any problems and I can create repositories etc.

I then try to do a docker login from within my EC2 instance like this:

```
docker login -u admin -p admin123 my_ip_address:8123
```

And after a while I get this:

```
Error response from daemon: Get http://my_ip_address/v1/users/: dial tcp my_ip_address:8123: i/o timeout
```

I have tried so many things to fix this and nothing seems to work. I spent so far an entire day trying to understand why docker login cannot see my Nexus3 registry.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's odd that the error response has http, it should be using https. One of our internal people said it seems like 8123 is not on https or the ip is inaccessible from your machine (but that seems odd given what you describe, too).

Comment: It baffles me too. I have tried more things since then and it simply doesn't work :)

Comment: Willing to help you out. If you reach out to me on my email I'll try and trouble shoot it with you, then we can post the answer here.

Comment: If you're using a self-signed certificate, make sure you add it to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/my_ip_address:8123/ca.key`
Also, make sure you add your IP address to the `http.addr` property of your config file, and restart both nexus and your docker daemon.

Comment: you can use `curl` to check if the repository available from outside, e.g `curl -I http://my_ip_address:8123/v2/` or `curl -I http://my_ip_address/v1/_ping` if v1 protocol is enabled in your repository options